# Can I set a browser Local Storage key value by using a redirect?

Tags: redirect, browser, local-storage

I'm trying to rework a web-ordering website to use as a kiosk, but it always asks for the "location" to order from when the kiosk app clears cookies/storage after sessions.

To skip the need for selecting the location, I noticed there's a local storage key labeled "persist:locations" which holds the value for the location we will be setting up the ordering kiosk. Is it at all possible for me to set the value for this key on domain A (owned by me) which then redirects guests to domain "B" while keeping the value for location key intact?

Answer (score 0):

> The localStorage read-only property of the window interface allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's **origin**;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Emphasis mine.

> Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port of the URL used to access it. Two objects have the same origin only when the scheme, hostname, and port all match.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin

So no this is not possible, localStorage can't be used across domains. I tried the same a while back to set authentication tokens to auto-log me in but could not work around that.